PDFs not loading without having /content/dam in the url in AEM 6.5
We have uploaded a pdf into DAM in AEM 6.5. Below is the path
/content/dam/XYZ/documents/en/pa/ABC.pdf.
But Users are using the link /XYZ/documents/en/pa/ABC.pdf in the page which was working before but now the pdf is not loading with this link. They cannot change the link with having /content/dam. Any idea why it is not loading.
Also I tried to add redirects using ACS common redirect manager.
Tried redirecting from /XYZ/documents/en/pa/ABC.pdf to /content/dam/XYZ/documents/en/pa/ABC.pdf when the url is hit but it is not working.
Any help is highly appreciated.

This could be due to a misconfigured rule on the dispatcher level, enable debug level on apache and check what's happening on the server when you try to access that URL
